# Redux time travel without dev tools?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flux, redux, redux-thunk

Is there any way to do time traveling with Redux core? From what I've seen it looks like this is only available using the devtools and not recommended for production. I was hoping to use redux in a multiplayer game to manage client server state reconciliation.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.

But you can always remove the Devtools from your production build and therefore only have it while developing.

[This link](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools#exclude-devtools-from-production-builds) might help?